# How can i hide the authors box from a specific set of categories and post types?

Tags: categories, theme-development, css, author

I want to just hide the authors box under the posts for few specific categories, while on the rest it will remain visible as is.

Comment: This is heavily dependent on the theme you use - note that questions regarding 3rd-party products are considered off-topic here, and are best addressed in the product in question's official support channels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on your theme. If it has no option for this, you'll have to do this yourself. Find the template where the author box is generated (presumably `single.php`) and copy it to a [child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes).

Then make the production of the box [conditional to the current category](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_category/);

```
if (!is_category (array ('exclude-this-category, another-category-to-exclude')) {
  echo '<div class="post-author-bio" itemprop="description">';
  ....
  echo '<div>';
  }
```

Comment: Most themes will create an action or a filter to edit this. Look for a filter or action for 'post_meta' or 'author_meta'. Then use remove_action('action_name') or add_filter('filter_name','custom_function_to_remove_div_on_cat').